# Rss feed - displays duplicate items

Tags: c#, xml, rss

I'm creating my own RSS files (XML) (c#.NET) to publish something and I'm using Outlook RSS to read them some of my friends too. It works ok, but sometimes for some reason I get duplicate items suddenly. When I look at the XML files I see their sinlge entries (not double).

I read posts in 2008 and 2010 which have the same problem. Now we are in year 2011 does Outlook still have this problem ?

1) Is it still true that Ms Outlook 2010 still gives that problem ?

2) I'm creating the XML files self so what do I need to change to avoid this issue?

I keep the published date on a table...

```
pubDate = (item.date_published == null) ? System.DateTime.Now.ToString("o") : Convert.ToDateTime(item.date_published).ToString("o");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your items have unique identifiers (preferably GUIDs) and that a single item receives only *one* identifier.

Comment: I tried <guid> the same value as link</guid> ->> this didn't help. I also tried <guid>Guid.newId().ToString()</guid>  ---> this didn't help neither ( I see the guid value when I do view source)... when I look with Internet explorer it even displays me sometimes 3, 4  multiply  (1 item 4 time).

Comment: I also tried "<guid isPermaLink="false"> link value</guid>. I still get duplicate items in Outlook and Googlereader. When I google I see many people has this problem, but no one has a fix... I'm still not understanding why I get duplicate items. How does reader detect for duplicate items??? what's the trigger?

Comment: Later I worked on this. I created a field in RSS TABLE and called rowGuid type: guid/uniqueidentifier - autoindent - which makes this row unqiue. I've put this value in rss XML <guid> rowguid</guid> now I don't get it double. so Anton guided me to right direction. thanks.